# Task after closing the tkinter window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, close-button

My program has to do some task after the `tkinter` window is closed.

When the 'X' button is pressed, it should print "The window is closed, how to do it"???

my code is

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
Label(root, text = "This is for stackoverflow('X' button clicked code)").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Actually I am looking for something like return value...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` protocol to detect if root window is closed.

```
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: print ("The window is closed."))
```

Also, `mainloop()` is a sort of while loop which keeps the GUI running.

You can also add `print('The window is closed.')` after it

```
root.mainloop()
print('The window is closed.')
```

Comment: in my program, the roots name is login_root, but it doesnot print the statement it gives the following error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\firstfrog\CodingBee\complete_app.py", line 2505, in <module>
    login_root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: print("The window is closed."))
  File "C:\python 32 bit\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2189, in wm_protocol
    return self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "wm" command: application has been destroyed

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the statement after the `mainloop()` ends. Look at @BryanOakley's comment -

```
root.mainloop()
print("The window is closed")
```

The print statement would not run until you close the window or when the mainloop ends

Edit - Maybe something like this will work -

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

l = tk.Label(root,text='hiiii')
l.pack()

root.mainloop()

print('The application is closed, new window opening')


win = tk.Tk()

l = tk.Label(win,text='byeee')
l.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: it works, but if i want to start a new process after that, it does not work

Comment: Edited code for you. I do not know if this qualifies as new process

Comment: thanks @PCM for trying to help me.... but my `mainloop` statement is located inside a function, but there this doesn't work... But thanks for trying to help me......